# Google Cloud SQL export to Storage as CSV compressed > Wrong Content Type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm exporting from a Google Cloud SQL MySQL to Google Cloud Storage, as CSV compressed.

This is the gcloud command:

```
gcloud sql export csv <MY_DB_INSTANCE> gs://export/myfile.gz  --query="MY_SQL_QUERY"
```

It works perfectly, a CSV gzip compressed is properly exported to Storage. However, the object file in Storage has set text/csv as content-type which is wrong. It should be application/gzip or at least have informed content-encoding.

[image]

I have try export also using the python library (googleapiclient) instead of gcloud command. Same result.

It seems to be a Google Cloud issue. Any idea about how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is gzipped? If so, you invoke a Google Cloud API (export in Cloud SQL) and the result isn't good. You can't fix it (except if you work at Google Cloud!). So, you have to report the bug and while it's fixed, you have to update yourselves the `content-encoding` to gzip.

Comment: Yep, it's gzipped for sure. I working on that sense.... programatically re-upload the file with the proper metadata.

Comment: Boring..... but no other solution for now

Comment: Hi, if this indeed an issue I don't think it can be solved by any user action. Could you create this issue on this Google Cloud Public Issue Tracker [component](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=1162714). This way it will reported to the Cloud SQL product team.